A movie about trapped people where they can only be back by being good
I'm looking for a movie about people trapped in a parallel world. They can only get back into the real world by being good. Killing yourself is not an option because you will be resurrected again. I heard about it through conversations, sounds interesting but the title is missing. A part of the movie is a character tried to electrocute himself in the bathtub but still no use as he was resurrected again.

Don't forget that you can add new details you remember directly into the question by using the little "edit" link under it. Also, don't you remember anything else that may help identification? What time was the movie likely from? What country was it likely from?

Is it Jet Li's "The One (2001)"?

Reminds me of Groundhog Day where Bill Murray's trapped in a time loop until he becomes a better person. He tries killing himself first (with a toaster in the bathtub, among other ways), but that doesn't work.

I was thinking Groundhog Day myself.

Alright, since more than one person has mentioned Groundhog Day (1993) and it seems correct but hasn't been posted as an answer yet, I guess I'll do the honors. 

Murray plays Phil Connors, an arrogant and egocentric Pittsburgh TV
  weatherman who, during an assignment covering the annual Groundhog Day
  event in Punxsutawney, Pennsylvania, finds himself in a time loop,
  repeating the same day again and again. After indulging in hedonism
  and numerous suicide attempts, he begins to re-examine his life and
  priorities.
  ...
  Eventually, Phil becomes depressed and tries more and more drastically
  to end the time loop; he gives ridiculous and offensive reports on the
  festival and eventually kidnaps Punxsutawney Phil and, after a police
  chase, drives off a high overlook into a quarry, killing both himself
  and the groundhog. However, Phil wakes up and finds that nothing has
  changed; further attempts at suicide are just as fruitless, as he
  continues to find himself waking at six o'clock on the morning of
  February 2 with the clock radio on his nightstand playing "I Got You
  Babe" by Sonny & Cher.  

Video clip of his suicide attempts, including the bathtub scene at the beginning.




When Phil explains the situation to Rita, she spends the day with him
  and into the early morning hours. But they fall asleep together and he
  awakens again stuck in the time loop. Inspired by her positive
  outlook, Phil endeavors to improve himself. He begins to use his
  by-now vast experience of the day to help as many people around town
  as possible. He uses the time to learn, among other things, how to
  play the piano, how to sculpt ice, and how to speak French.
Eventually, Phil is able to befriend almost everyone he meets during
  the day, using his experiences to save lives, to help townspeople, and
  ultimately to get closer to Rita. He crafts a report on the Groundhog
  Day celebration so eloquent that all the other stations turn their
  microphones to him. After the town's evening dance, Rita "buys" Phil
  at the event's bachelor auction. Phil makes a snow sculpture of Rita's
  face and they kiss for the first time. The moment they kiss, the snow
  begins to fall, which had never happened before, implying to the
  audience that their kiss has broken the time loop. They retire to his
  room. He wakes the next morning and finds the time loop is, in fact,
  broken; it is now February 3 and Rita is still with him.

They walk outside and Phil declares that they shall live there (renting initially).

This is a shot in the dark, but your description reminds me of the movie Nothing (2003).

Can you add a bit more about why you think 'Nothing' is the movie he is looking for?
